# Pick random element on an Array and put it on a JLabel

Tags: java

I'm trying to make a Pinoy Henyo Game and I want my text to randomly generate to my JLabel using an array, does anyone can help me with this? I was trying to search the net but I can't find anything. Here's some of my code:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class SuperHenyo extends JFrame implements ActionListener {
    String bagay[] = {
        "Gitara", "Timba", "Tuwalya", "Telebisyon", "Laptop", "Bintilador", "Relo", "Jacket", "Medyas", "Bumbilya"
    };
    JButton bBtn = new JButton("BAGAY");
    public SuperHenyo() {}
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if (e.getSource() == bBtn) {

        }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a `java.util.Random` to generate a random `int` value which can act as an index into your array

Something like...

```
Random rnd = new Random();
int index = rnd.nextInt(bagay.length);
String text = bagay[index];
```

But personally, I would create the `Random` as a instance field of the class and re-use as you need

See [How to Use Labels](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/label.html) for more details about how to work with `JLabel`s

Comment: if someone helps you then please accept his answer as well @Newbie10 :)